# Selenium Webdriver and XStudio

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does anybody know how to setup XStudio to run Selenium Webdriver Tests?

I cannot find any documentation or information about that. There is only one mention on the XQual website that selenium 2.0-webdriver is supported.
Can anyone help me?

I need an explanation how to setup the software, which launcher I need to choose and how to configure the tests. Perhaps someone also knows a good tutorial for webdriver with xstudio or some documentation on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [doc](http://www.xqual.com/documentation/launchers/selenium_java.html) is not useful for your purposes. It is based on Selenium 1 (i.e Selnium RC), which was deprecated long time ago. You need to use Selenium WebDriver, i.e. Selenium 2, or even better, [Selenium 3](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2016/10/13/selenium-3-0-out-now/).

I am not an expert of XStudio, but maybe you might try to use the [JUnit launcher](http://www.xqual.com/documentation/launchers/junit.html), and inside the test logic, use Selenium WebDriver to carry out your web testing.

Standalone examples of Selenium Webdriver can be found [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples).

Comment: i will try that

Comment: I tried it but my tests are not running... I get errors "execution error" and "run:no result". I really need help with config!!!!

Answer (score 1):

running Webdriver tests is basically the same as running the former selenium tests.So you can follow these instructions:
http://www.xqual.com/documentation/launchers/selenium_html.html

Comment: ok so i do not need to specify the path to the driver server paths or something? just run the driver tests with the default config?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with many of these launchers, the best is to first activate the traces so that you see exactly what the launcher is doing.
To do that, follow the instructions here: http://www.xqual.com/support/faq.html#question15

Then share your traces. I should be able to help as I am using many different launchers...